# How to stop flex-grow from exceeding max-width setting, and wrap instead?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am learning flexbox and reached the following dilemma:
please see below code.

If you notice .child1 (grey box) is pushing .child2 (green box) to the right off the screen.  The .parent has a max-width property (blue border), and it's violated.

I want child1 to grow to max width, but when max-width is reached it should wrap content within child1 instead.  How do we accomplish this?

Setting both child1 ands child2 to grow-shrink is problematic because I want child1 to take maximum width up until max-width is reached. (otherwise both will take minimum width if content is small)

```css
.grandParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.parent {
background: lightred;
display: flex;
max-width: 300px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
.child1 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.child2 {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1">child1 some more text even more text now is hello dlks jflksj dlkfsj dlksdlk f</div>
<div class="child2">child2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: flex-wrap: wrap; to parent?

Comment: For `.child1` set `flex: 1 0;` or just remove it from declaration.